# Created R Package, Unable to Display Photo

Tags: r

Update

Issue resolved

---

Update, still not working

Tried the following in R file

(1) deleted both library(...) packages

(2) Added `@import jpeg` before `ShowPalettePhoto()` and `@import tidyverse` before `RanglaPunjab()` so roxygen automatically adds to NAMESPACE.

After running `devtools::document()`, ran `devtools::use_package("jpeg")` and `devtools::use_package("tidyverse")` to automatically add to DESCRIPTION.

Unfortunately, even in testing, I cannot get JPEG photo.

Here is GitHub repository, https://github.com/ArtieLadie/RanglaPunjab

---

I created R package according to this [tutorial](https://hilaryparker.com/2014/04/29/writing-an-r-package-from-scratch/)

It worked and I was able to execute all commands, including a function to display photo in another directory.

I uploaded to my [GitHub account](https://github.com/ArtieLadie/RanglaPunjab). Anyone can install package in R environment with `install_github("ArtieLadie/RanglaPunjab")`

I am able to run functions by adding `RanglaPunjab::` in front of it, i.e.

```
RanglaPunjab::PaintPalette("Jutti")
?RanglaPunjab::MergePalette
```

However, when I try to run `?RanglaPunjab::ShowPalettePhoto("Teej")` I get

```
Error in readJPEG(x, native = TRUE) : could not find function "readJPEG"
```

Before creating the package I added function to set working directory to file location, but it was creating errors when I ran `install("RanglaPunjab")`, i.e. `"Cannot execute"`

Here are the exact commands I had, which I had to delete from code

```
library(rstudioapi) 
current_path <- getActiveDocumentContext()$path 
setwd(dirname(current_path ))
```

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dependencies are not handled correctly. [Here](https://github.com/ArtieLadie/RanglaPunjab/blob/master/R/RanglaPunjab.R#L1-L2) you explicitly load packages with `library(...)`. That is not how one does that in an R package. You should add your dependencies to the `Imports:` section of the `DESCRIPTION` file and use the `package::function()` syntax when calling the function. c.f. http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/description.html#dependencies.

In addition, if you want the images to be installed with your package, you should place them for example in `inst/pics`. You can then get the path to these files with

```
system.file("pics", <file-name>, package = "RanglaPunjab")
```

Comment: Still not working. Tried the following in R file (1) deleted both library(...) packages  (2) Added `@import jpeg` before `ShowPalettePhoto()` and `@import tidyverse` before `RanglaPunjab() `so roxygen automatically adds to NAMESPACE. After running `devtools::document()`, ran `devtools::use_package("jpeg")` and `devtools::use_package("tidyverse")` to automatically add to DESCRIPTION. Unfortunately, even in testing, I cannot get JPEG photo. Please see repository, "ArtieLadie/RanglaPunjab"

Comment: When I run `ShowPalettePhoto("Teej")` Error is `Error in readJPEG(x, native = TRUE) : unable to open ./Photos/teej.jpg' `Other commands run without error.

Comment: @ArtieLadie You probably want to install the pictures along with the package.  See updated answer.

Comment: I loaded the library and tried `system.file("pics", "teej.jpg", package = "RanglaPunjab")` (system.files is non-existant). Output is `[1] ""`

Comment: @ArtieLadie Typo in my answer: it should reed `system.file` without the plural s.

Comment: Still having problem, HELP. I identified the system directory, i.e. C:\Users\<username>\Documents\R\win-library\3.5\, but where would I place photos so they end up installed with package, i.e. automatically appearing in system directory? I tried placing in R directory, but still no luck :-(

Comment: @ArtieLadie You don’t have to do this manually. The `inst` folder is at the same level as the (source) R folder. The content of this folders copied verbatim to the installation folder.

Comment: Well, since `inst` folder wasn't created, let me create and see what happens

Comment: Your answer pointed me in the correct direction. Still tinkering with code. Thank you :-)

Comment: I created separate question. Kindly answer if possible, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50490007/r-package-unable-to-access-contents-from-inst-folder