# R Package unable to access contents from `inst` folder

Tags: r, directory-structure

Update

Fixed it

```
  x <- tolower(name)
  sysloc <- system.file(package="RanglaPunjab")
  x <- paste (sysloc,"/img/",x,".jpg", sep="")
  jj <- readJPEG(x,native=TRUE)
  plot(0:1,0:1,type="n",ann=FALSE,axes=FALSE)
  rasterImage(jj,0,0,1,1)
```

---

I created R package according to this [tutorial](https://hilaryparker.com/2014/04/29/writing-an-r-package-from-scratch/)

From what I understand, folder `inst` will include all the files verbatim in final package. I included directory `img` with all the photos that `ShowPalettePhoto(name)` should display

R package is located on GitHub, https://github.com/ArtieLadie/RanglaPunjab

Below is photo of System Files directory (after installing package on my machine)

`img` folder is in same level as `R`. Function `ShowPalettePhoto(name)` accesses the jpg with following command.

```
  x <- paste ("./img/",x,".jpg", sep="")
  jj <- readJPEG(x,native=TRUE)
  plot(0:1,0:1,type="n",ann=FALSE,axes=FALSE)
  rasterImage(jj,0,0,1,1)
```

Where am I going wrong?

```
Error in readJPEG(x, native = TRUE) : unable to open ./img/teej.jpg
```

[image]

Comment: The "." in the path would be the "current working directory" of you R session. Not the package. Use the `system.file()` function to get files from your package.

Comment: It is a basic misunderstanding on your part. _Everything in `inst/` becomes installed "as-is"_ but without the `inst/` layer. See the duplicate I marked.

Comment: Trying this out .... will keep you posted

Comment: Fixed it , see updated question